# Unable to edit review audits

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just had a review audit with a very bad grammar. Everything like *i* or sentence beginnings was lowercased, so I decided to edit the question. As I clicked on the `edit` link below the question, I get redirected to a page that says that the post was deleted and can't be edited. Then I clicked on the link to get to the real question and it was also deleted.

What should I do with those review audits? It's impossible to handle it like a normal question where I should have edited it. Also, if I notice that I have a review audit instead of a normal review, why should I continue? Shouldn't review audits be questions or answers that still exist so that you can edit it (the edit needn't affect the question) and that you don't notice that you have a review audit in front of you?

Comment: I thought a review audit was a closed or deleted answer or question, that is brought back up again to test you. So you wouldn't need to edit it. So just decide on it like you would a normal question.   (I don't have enough rep to know for sure how it works, but this is what I've picked up.)

Comment: @DonyorM Yes, on a normal question I would have edited it

Comment: Is a review audit actually just a set-up test that happens while review flags?

Comment: @DonyorM A rewiev audit is a something that looks like a normal review but is a test if you take care while reviewing - so I should be able to handle it like a normal question

Comment: I read another post about this, and I'm pretty sure that review audits are old questions, either closed or deleted, that are randomly selected to be shown as a test. So you can't actually edit them because they no longer exist. They're just a test. Then again I could be wrong, I'm still too low of rep.

Comment: @DonyorM Thats correct, but I should treat a review audit as a normal review - and I can't do that if I can't edit it

Comment: So did you fail or pass the audit? If you passed the audit, then there's no problem - you told the review system that the post needed work, but since the post had already been deleted, that would be pointless.

Comment: @SLBarth I skipped the review

Answer (score 2):

So you're in the review queue, and you find a post that is so poorly phrased, that you need to edit it first.... but it turns out the post is already deleted.

So, apparently the post is an audit. You have shown that you were paying attention, so click "Recommend Deletion" and continue.
The system could let you edit the whole post first, but that would be a waste of your time - the post is already deleted.

Review audits are deliberately taken from the pool of deleted posts, because these are considered known examples of bad posts. (To be fair, the system doesn't always choose posts that are appropriate for reviews, but that's another discussion - check the [disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) tag if you want to know more).

On closing, choosing "Skip" like you did was also a good choice. When in doubt, skip.

Comment: Well, the only options I had were "No Action Needed" which would have leaded to fail the audit, or "Skip"

Comment: In the First Posts queue, you can upvote or downvote. Normally you'd want to edit a post into shape before passing judgment, but in this case you've already found that it was a review, so downvoting is ok here.