# Reviewing posts: easy test exploit

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

When I was reviewing other's **Late Answers** and **First Posts**, I found that when a 'test' post opens up, and when I click on 'edit', it says: "You cannot edit deleted post" (or something like this). So in conclusion: it is very easy to detect when you have a test post, and not a real one.

***Question:*** Where and how can I report this?

Comment: Not all audit posts concern deleted posts. You are paying enough attention to detect *some* audits, the system is already working.

Comment: You can also just go to the question itself and see if it is there.  If it isn't, then clearly it has been deleted and should be deleted as such.

Comment: Or when the post was posted 2 hours ago, when most posts are only 15 mins...

Comment: FWIW in LQ reviews, [clicking Edit fails known bad audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274804/why-does-just-clicking-edit-fail-review-audit)

Comment: Works fine until the audit spits out something it thinks is bad and you click edit. Then you fail the audit because you tried to edit. Note that the audit system is broken, so what it thinks is a bad post is not necessarily so, or vice versa.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269829/3755692

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> when I click on 'edit', it says: "You cannot edit deleted post"

Congratulations.  You're not a robo-reviewer.  Or, to put it another way, "Mission accomplished."

(Is a robo-reviewer really going to bother clicking on the Edit link and dismissing a dialog, just to make sure he's not hitting a review?)

Comment: A robo-reviewer can simply spam random actions on non-deleted (aka, the legit posts), and skip the posts that are 'deleted'

Comment: it is not very hard to make a bot like that, if someone would want to do that, he would do it without a problem.

Comment: @Victor2748 I believe there is more intelligence, checks in addition to this one, and more dev thought about potential *this-and-that* than you know or give credit for ;) If a robo skips any deleted, then they do not get their *precious* edit points. Random actions will likely not get them very far, and after a few failed audits, their "bot" will be "spanked". All that said, you can't always cover every angle *and* allow a system to remain useful/functional.

Comment: If you create a robo-reviewer that can intelligently analyze posts, then there's no reason to stop it :p

Comment: @ChrisBaker [Obligatory XKCD](http://xkcd.com/810/).

Comment: The thing to do is to make Firefox and Chrome plugins that can be called up when revieweing.  A clever plugin could identify the audits so that people don't waste their time on it.

Comment: There are easier ways to detect audits if you are an actual robot..

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, there certainly are. One way is to use the 1k+ ability to check vote counts inline and see if the vote count after clicking matches the previously displayed vote count, or if an error occurs when obtaining the vote count. This is one easy way (for 1k+ rep users) to detect audits.

Comment: @Paul Just click to see the vote count, as I described in my above comment.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi There are easier ways. You are thinking like a human. Look at robots can see. Wink, wink.